# Why is my SD Card not writable (Android)?

Tags: android, storage, sd-card

In the emulator I can't seem to write to the attached SDCard. The following code always spits out the "can't write root" log message, but not the "can't read root" one.

```
File routesRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
if (!routesRoot.canWrite())
    Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "can't write root");
if (!routesRoot.canRead())
    Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "can't read root");
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check, and then double check that you have the [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this was introduced in API level 4 (Android 1.6)... it "just worked" before that.

Comment: If you're working with the real device, make sure to unplug it from the machine. At least for me, it didnt work just unmounting the sdcard.